# PayPal embedded checkout page returns to incorrect page

Tags: paypal

I am integrating a PayPal hosted checkout page using Layout C to display the page in an iframe on my client's website. When I complete a test purchase, the iframe redirects to a page on the website that is not the URL specified as the return URL in PayPal Manager. Is there another place I need to change this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set it in the account.  What URL is it taking you back to?  Can you capture what you are sending over to the hosted page and see if you are passing anything over in there that would be causing the issue.  Can you provide a link to your check out so that we can test it?  I can also take a look at the account settings on my side to make sure they are correct, but setting it in the account should work.

Comment: You helped me discover the issue. The SDK I was using was sending a different return URL (and error URL) than what I had defined.

But perhaps you could help with a related question...In Google Chrome, the hosted iframe page fails to load the image that should appear under the "Bill Me Later" button. The image loads just fine in other browsers, just not in Chrome.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your checkout to see what it is doing.